# Dbeaver doesn't display metadata from one of our hive instances. How to fix?

Tags: hive, dbeaver, database-metadata, data-lake

We use the DBeaver to connect to our hive datalake. I've found a very strange behavior. We have a test and a production datalake.

In our test datalake it correctly displays the tables metadata in the Project tab (the left column). Here it is:

[image: Metadata correctly displayed]

But when I go to the our hive production connection, and click in the small arrow beside the schema, no metadata is displayed:

[image: No metadata displayed]

The weirdest thing is that if I execute the command `show tables` or `describe table_name`, the metadata is correctly displayed. So *I have all the permissions to display it.*

I've compared all configurations that I've found trying to debug this problem, but don't know what to do any more. A datalake admin helped me since I don't have all the permissions to it.

We use kerberos and a Jdbc connection to Hive.

**How to make dbeaver display my metadata ?** What should I check to try to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the driver from Uber jdbc to [Cloudera's ODBC Hive Driver](https://www.cloudera.com/downloads/connectors/hive/odbc/2-6-11.html) and now everything is working fine. I can see the tables metadata and it looks like the connection is quicker.

When configuring your Hive ODBC Data Source, open the Advanced Options and be sure that `Get Tables With Query` checkbox is marked.

[image: Check Get Tables With Query option]

Answer (score 0):

Please see if Connection type or Navigator View setting can help fix your issue. Please see attached picture for reference.[image]